# Cannot install/run pip install -U sentence-transformers

Tags: python, pip, sentence-transformers

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall the packages and several other dependencies.

Here's my error:

```
 Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [31 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\17605\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\17605\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\17605\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\17605\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6gejxtmm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\17605\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6gejxtmm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\17605\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6gejxtmm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\17605\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6gejxtmm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 126, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\17605\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 408, in check_call
          retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\17605\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\17605\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Users\17605\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I'm kind of new to python so could really use some help here. I'm also using PyCharm as an IDE but i don't think that mattes at all and i'm using the bash terminal inside the IDE.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Wow, that's a surprisingly useless stack trace -- no mention of what the executable it's trying to start that's not found is. Can you run that under pdb (Python's debugger) so you can inspect the value of `executable` in that last frame?

Comment: Sure let me try that now.

Comment: Actually, not sure how to do that, like i was saying kind of new to python. It's a built in module, correct? Not something i need to install, right?

Comment: (the `exec()` in that stack trace is code that's typically called to run a `setup.py` file, but the one for sentence-transformers itself doesn't have anywhere close to 126 lines and also doesn't try to run any subprocesses -- so it smells like this is some dependency having the problem, not sentence-transformers itself).

Comment: note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
The program exited via sys.exit(). Exit status: 1
> c:\users\17605\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py(1)<module>()
-> import os
(Pdb) print(executable)
*** NameError: name 'executable' is not defined
(Pdb) print(executable) 
*** NameError: name 'executable' is not defined
(Pdb)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256884/discussion-between-head-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 0):

To install `sentence-transformers`, it is recommended to use Python 3.8 or higher, and at least `PyTorch 1.11.0`. See [installation](https://www.sbert.net/docs/installation.html) for further installation options.

I'd suggest you downgrade your Python version as it is not yet clear whether this package supports your Python 3.12.